# Count up numbers from a specific column

Tags: sql-server, php, count, number-formatting

Hi there was wondering if someone could help me out, and can give me a little code example.
i have a table named "projecten", and columns named "pstatus and pafgifte" these columns have numbers only.
I would like to count up all "pafgifte" with "pstatus = 2" only, and echo result.

help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have a look at [COUNT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/count-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: In addition to `COUNT`, you will need to `GROUP BY` your fields. If you're still having problems, get back to us - I realise that not everybody was born knowing SQL! p.s. welcome to the forum! :-)

Comment: request, to receive simple code example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this:

```
select sum(case when pstatus=2 then pafgifte else 0 end) pafgifte_total
from projecten
```

Assuming you mean to add the numbers together.

Comment: thank you for your example